# javascript if state function doesn't read boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code work with resize function boolean change with width,
but my function contain if statement doesn't read the boolean,
what is problem with my code?

I used = ==, but I don't know how to use them exactly

```
var footerMenu = ['#about', '#help']
var slideSwitch = false

function slideDown(){
  footerMenu.forEach(function(list){
      $(list+' p').click(function(){
        $(list+' ul').slideToggle(300)
      })
    })
}

function slideClear(){
  for( let i = 0; i < footerMenu.length; i++){ 
    $(footerMenu[i]+' p').click(function(){
      var choice = footerMenu[i]
      footerMenu.splice(i, 1);
      footerMenu.forEach(function(list){ 
      $(list+' ul').slideUp(300)
      })
      footerMenu.splice(i, 0, choice);
    })
  }
}

function slideTotal(){
  if(slideSwitch = true){
    slideDown()
    slideClear()
  } 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkWidth();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
  checkWidth();
});

function checkWidth(){
  $vWidth = $(window).width();

  if($vWidth <576){
       console.log("Width: Less than 576");
       slideSwitch = true
  }else{
       console.log("Width: More than 576");
      slideSwitch = false
  } 
}

slideTotal()
```

I hope correct my code, if I don't have any wrong please advice me how to solve it

Comment: This: `slideSwitch = true` is an assignment statement - not an equality evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator. It changes the value of what is on the left hand side. It is usually **not** what you want in an if statement unless you really know what you are doing.

`==` and `===` are the comparison operators. The different between them is that `==` automatically converts the two arguments to the same type, whereas `===` does not. But that doesn't really matter, my advice is to *always* use `===` to compare variables in an if statement.

Also, comparing to true (`x === true`) is completely pointless because that is what an if statement already does; it is unnecessary.

(side note: you could do `if (x === true === true === true)`, and that would be the same as `if (x)`.)

The code you want is:

```
function slideTotal() {
  if (slideSwitch) {
    slideDown();
    slideClear();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start:

```
function slideTotal(){
  if(slideSwitch = true){
    slideDown()
    slideClear()
  } 
}
```

change: `slideSwitch = true`
to: `slideSwitch == true`